# Seeking .Net alternative to Mapxtreme

Tags: openlayers-2, software-recommendations, .net, tilecache

I was involved in a project that used MapXtreme server and MapXtreme SDK to query the tabs (as in SearchNearest , SearchInRadius etc...)

I'm looking for an open source alternative that I can integrate in .Net web app that will use OpenLayers + Tile Cache and I'll be able to query Tab (or Shape) files after the user pin the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) in the past for this. I was using it for an ASP.NET application and it was very easy to use it as a WMS server with OpenLayers as the client.